# Display content through ActiveRecord_Association_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have a Products model with a 'has_many' relationship to Microposts. Likewise, Microposts has a 'belongs_to' relationship to Products. throught this relationship I want to populate a row in table with all the available microposts for that product. From what I can tell the association works fine and the rows have potential to display the content, however "#Micropost::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa5ba8b4d60" is displayed instead of the actual content.

**Micropost.rb**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :product_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save{
self.name = name.downcase.humanize}
before_save{
self.oem = oem.downcase.humanize}

validates :ta_code,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 4, minimum: 3 }
validates :tatr,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 4, minimum: 4 },       uniqueness: true
validates :name,  presence: true
validates :oem,  presence: true
validates :kind,  presence: true
validates :ta_type,  presence: true
has_many :microposts
end
```

**code**

```
<% Product.all.each do |product| %>
.
.
.
<% if product.microposts.any? %>
            <ul class="microposts">
              <% product.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
              <li><%= micropost.content %></li>
              <% end %>
              </ul>
            <%= link_to "Update status", new_status_path(product_id: product.id), :method => :create %>
            <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Update status", new_status_path(product_id: product.id), :method => :create %>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply change the display part to the following

```
<% Product.all.each do |product| %>
.
.
.
  <ul class="microposts">
    <%product.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
      <li><%=micropost.content%></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same ActiveRecord_association_CollectionProxy display

Comment: Oh my bad, i made a slight mistake in the answer, I have corrected it. please do let me know if it works now.

Comment: Still the same display

Comment: how about now? it now should list out the content of the micropost.

Comment: I actually just tried that. It doesn't change anything on the actual webpage, but when I try to use it using the console I get an undefined method error

Comment: does this work on console `Product.all.map(&:microposts)`? and please do try restarting your server once.

Comment: Yes, I can see all the microposts. In this case there is 2 of them both associated with the product I'm testing. '#<Micropost id: 3, content: "create micropost", product_id: 13, created_at: "2015-06-29 15:19:07", updated_at: "2015-06-29 15:19:07">]>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>]'

Comment: Could you update your question with how your view looks now.

Comment: everything looks perfectly fine. I cant understand why it is behaving so differently. have you tried restarting your app?

Comment: This is embarrassing and I'm sorry for wasting your time. It appears that I was updating the view for the incorrect tab. What you suggested did fix the problem. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Sure, we have all been through there :)